# How to print every third element of Array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need to take 2 inputs from user size of array and then elements of that same array.

I need to print every third element of array.

Example Array: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Desired output: 3,6,9 
Getting:  9,6,3

```
class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;
        int[] y;

        Scanner tastatura = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter size of array:");

        x = tastatura.nextInt();
        y = new int[x];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of array:");

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            y[i] = tastatura.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\n Every third element of array is : ");

        for (int i = y.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 3) {
            System.out.println(y[i]);
        }
        tastatura.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close!  You just have the iteration order reversed!

```
for (int i = y.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 3) {
    System.out.println(y[i]);
}
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 2; i < y.length; i += 3) {
    System.out.println(y[i]);
}
```

Take note that this can throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your array does not contain at least `3` elements, so you should handle that somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

use the modulus operator to find each 3rd item.

example 

    0 % 3 = 0
    1 % 3 = 1
    2 % 3 = 2
    3 % 3 = 0

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i =0 ; i < y.length - 1; i = i + 3) {
        System.out.println(y[i]);
    }
```

The way you are printing is in reverse order .. Correct that

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track I would strongly recommend using a modulus:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if(i%3==0){
    System.out.println(y[i]);
   }//if statement
}//for loop
```